# C# Override DefaultValue attribute?

Tags: c#, user-controls, overriding

is it possible, in a C# user control, to override an attribute applied to a property, without having to override the property ?

Say, for example, you want a property which, as inherited, has the "Browsable(true)" attribute, but for your control, you want "Browsable(false)". Do you have to override the property itself, or can you do something with, perhaps, the TypeDescriptor ?

If the property is not virtual, overriding is not possible and, while using "new" is possible, you then cannot access the property with a reference to a base class (like "Control").

ie. Simple example to change default for ScrollBars on a textbox control.

```
public partial class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
  public MyTextBox()
  {
     this.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
  }

  [DefaultValue(typeof(ScrollBars),"Vertical")]
  public ScrollBars ScrollBars
  {
     get { return base.ScrollBars; }
     set { base.ScrollBars = value; }
  }
}

// this doesn't go via property setter as not overridden
TextBox textbox = new MyTextBox();
textbox.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
```

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you can't do it without overriding. If the property is not virtual - you're doomed.